# Where can you get more VS2010 themes?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vssettings

I am not talking about the code editor.  I have already imported my Visual Studio setting to change the color markup of my project files I am now wanting to change the Theme of Visual Studio to a darker theme using [Theme plugin in the Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378).  Is there anywhere to go to get a pre-crafted dark theme, as the default ones it comes with are quite poor?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

It seems that both link are dead :( Here are the link from the way back machine :)

- [Visual Studio 2010 Dark Expression Blend Color Theme](http://web.archive.org/web/20130905144604/http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme)
- [Elite Dark](http://web.archive.org/web/20121003044414/http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Pimp-Your-IDE-Visual-Studio-2010-Themes-and-Skins.aspx)

---

Here are some:

[Visual Studio 2010 Dark Expression Blend Color Theme](http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme):

[Visual Studio 2010 Dark Expression Blend Color Theme http://www.nerdpad.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/vs2010_expression_thumb.jpg](http://www.nerdpad.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/vs2010_expression_thumb.jpg)

[Elite Dark:](http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Pimp-Your-IDE-Visual-Studio-2010-Themes-and-Skins.aspx)

[image: Elite Dark]

---

And just a side note:

But if you're looking color **schemes** (not **themes**), you can find it here: [studiostyl.es](http://studiostyl.es/). This is a great resource dedicated to share `VS` themes.

Comment: @tpaksu: the first one (*Expression Blend*)

Comment: can someone Update those Links? They are broken! I would love the Dark Theme, can´t find anywhere

Comment: @Alex Elite Dark's download link is dead. Do you have a mirror by any chance?

Comment: @Boumbles: unfortunately, I have no another link to the theme, but I asked the author to update the dead link

Answer (score 9):

Try http://studiostyl.es/.

There are many similar sites, but this one hosts many themes.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any existing ones, but here is how I made my own dark theme.

1. Go to the `Theme->Customize Colors` menu
2. Click the highlighted `new theme` link and name your theme
3. Back on the main theme dialog, select all the available colors (click on one row in that table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to select all)
4. (Optional) If you want to change the color to be slightly different, click on the `Colorize` button (it's the right-most button on the top row)
5. Click the `Modify Hue/Saturation/Lightness` button (second-from-right on the top row).  Move the saturation and lightness sliders to the left to get the effect you want (decreasing saturation removes color and makes everything grayer, decreasing lightness makes things darker without removing color).

I've made a few "themes" like this; a lighter/blue-er theme, a dark (gray) theme, and a dark (red) theme.

Answer (score 1):

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ is the closest we've got so far, and the only dark theme is already individually linked above. Bit of a niche opportunity ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a (freeware) app that lets you create VS themes quickly by letting you select lots of colours and, for example, randomize a particular channel. You can create a dark theme in a couple of mouse clicks.
The zip also includes 3 themes. I've just put it for now in  http://www.filedude.com/download/7g4YH3FRpQb0c76202d2.